# Addresses of dynamically allocated arrays spoil depending on the way the array is declared?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

The following code seems to work when the array is declared like

```
int numbers[3]
```

But when I try declaring it like

```
int* numbers = new int[3];
```

After resizing the resized array's first two numbers seem to get lost.
I can't really figure out what is the difference betwean the two declarations. Any clarification will be helpfull.

```
int main() {
  int numbers_size = 0;
  int numbers_capacity = 3;
  //works when declared like this
  //does not work when declared like int* numbers = new int[3]
  int numbers[3];
  do {
    ...
    if(numbers_capacity == numbers_size)
      numbers_capacity = resize_array(numbers, numbers_size);
  }while(numbers[numbers_size - 1] != 0);
  return 0;
}

int resize_array(int* arr, int arr_size) {
  int* temp = new int[arr_size];
  for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    temp[i] = arr[i];
  delete [] arr;
  arr = new int[4*arr_size];
  for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
    arr[i] = temp[i];
  }
  delete [] temp;
  return 4*arr_size;
}
```

Comment: Such kind of problems are best solved stepping through your code line by line using a decent debugger, not by asking on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the value of `arr` in `resize_array` to point to new memory location but the calling function still has the old, now dangling, memory location.

Change the function to:

```
int* resize_array(int* arr, int arr_size)
{
   int* temp = new int[arr_size];
   for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
      temp[i] = arr[i];

   delete [] arr; // This makes pointer in the calling function
                  // point to deleted memory.

   arr = new int[4*arr_size];
   for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
      arr[i] = temp[i];
   }
   delete [] temp;

   // Return the newly allocated memory.
   return arr;
}
```

and use it like:

```
numbers_capacity = numbers_size*4; // This is bad. It assumes that
                                   // that you are increasing the size by 4 times.

numbers = resize_array(numbers, numbers_size);
```

You can simply use a `std::vector<int>` and avoid all the headache.